# "undefined symbol: libiconv" but no linkage to libiconv?

Tags: python, gcc, linker, lxml, loader

I've just compiled lxml for python and I try to import it:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /<truncated>/lxml/etree.cpython-34m.so: undefined symbol: libiconv
```

But oddly enough, no `libiconv` in the dynamic libraries:

```
$ ldd /<truncated>/lxml/etree.cpython-34m.so
librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00002b32e2371000)
libgcrypt.so.11 => /usr/lib64/libgcrypt.so.11 (0x00002b32e257a000)
libz.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00002b32e27ec000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00002b32e2a01000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002b32e2c84000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002b32e2e9f000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000000305fc00000)
libgpg-error.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00002b32e31f7000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00002b32e33fa000)
```

But I use `nm`: and I see it has libiconv as a symbol:

```
$ nm /<truncated>/lxml/etree.cpython-34m.so | grep iconv
             U libiconv
             U libiconv_close
             U libiconv_open
```

I'm not understanding something here because I can't figure out how to make it see that symbol.

In case you're wondering about the build command I used to install `lxml` was

```
CFLAGS="-fPIC" LDFLAGS="-lrt -lgcrypt -liconv" STATIC_DEPS=true pip install lxml
```

Comment: Did you get a solution? I had a similar problem. I was on a machine I didn't have root access to, so I ended up (1) Downloading the sources for libxml, libxslt, lxml (2) Compiling each of those sources by hand, updating the $PATH, $LD_LIBRARY_PATH and $PYTHONPATH appropriately. Everything works for me now. I did not use pip. If you would like to know more, I can comment with the steps I followed.

Comment: having the same problem here. if you could post the steps that'd be great thanks